# How to prevent post to repeat on my loop?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

i'm new at wordpress development and i created custom post type to include in a Bootstrap carousel. It works but is repeating my first slide. How can i prevent this?

Here's my code:

```
<section role="banners-wrapper" class="row">
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'Banners', 
            'posts_per_page' => 1 
        ));
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php the_field('banner-image'); ?>">
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'Banners', 
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'offset' => 1 
            ));
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php the_field('banner-image'); ?>">
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
</section>
```

Any thoughts?
Best regards

Comment: What happens if you set posts per page to a very high number instead of -1?

Comment: Try putting your numbers in single quotes.  'posts_per_page' => '1'?  But why are you doing this in 2 loops?

Comment: `'offset'` does not work with `'posts_per_page' => -1` - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment by @Michael,

> `offset` does not work with `'posts_per_page' => -1`

You can possibly use increment to make first slide as `active`, in a single loop.

Use this

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'Banners', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1 
    ));
    $i = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="carousel-item <?php if($i == 0) { echo 'active'; } ?>">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php the_field('banner-image'); ?>">
    </div>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You may accept the working answer and make it useful for others.